# Is there a way to bundle multiple packages together with Python setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have packages A and B, both have their own git repository, PyPI page, etc...  Package A depends on package B, and by using the `install_requires` keyword I can get A to automatically download and install B.

But suppose I want to go a step further for my especially non-savvy users; I want to actually include package B within the tar/zip for package A, so no download is necessary (this also lets them potentially make any by-hand edits to package B's `setup.cfg`)

Is there a suggested (ideally automated) way to,

- Include B in A when I call `sdist` for A
- Tell setuptools that B is bundled with A for resolving the dependency (something like a local `dependency_links`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is called 'vendorizing' and no, there is no support for such an approach.

It is also a bad idea; you want to leave installation to the specialized tools, which not only manage dependencies but also what versions are installed. With tools like [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) or [pip's requirements.txt format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) you can control very precisely what versions are being used.

By bundling a version of a dependency inside, you either force upon your users what version they get to use, or make it harder for such tools to ensure the used versions for a given installation are consistent. In addition, you are potentially wasting bandwidth and space; if other packages have also included the same requirements, you now have multiple copies. And if your dependency is updated to fix a critical security issue, you have to re-release any package that bundles it.

In the past, some packages did use vendorize packaging to include a dependency into their distribution. `requests` was a prime example; they stepped away from this approach because it complicated their release process. Every time there was a bug in one of the vendored packages they had to produce a new release to include the fix, for example.

If you do want to persist in including packages, you'll have to write your own support. I believe `requests` manually just added the vendorized packages to their repository; so they kept a static copy they updated from time to time. Alternatively, you could extend `setup.py` to download code when you are creating a distribution.

Comment: I agree its a little weird, but if you indulge me for a second... All I want to do is provide a "dependency_link" for project B for setuptools (or any other compatible build system) to find. I just happen to want to put it inside of the ``sdist`` tarball for project A. Why is that so bad?

Comment: @marius: why is a second download by an automated tool so bad? :-)

Comment: I suppose its mostly what I put in parenthesis, mainly that I sort of expect project B might require some tinkering of the ``setup.cfg``, and for my non-Python-savvy users I want project B's ``setup.cfg`` sitting right there ready for tinkering should anything go wrong when setuptools tries to resolve the dependecy.