# How to package dependencies with a Python application?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools

I have a Python application that I'm distributing with the standard setup.py. I need to package the dependencies too because the audience I'm distributing do not have network access. I have downloaded the packages from PyPi but am stuck where to place them so when someone does "python setup.py install", they will get installed.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, I'm trying to achieve this on a Unix platform and without using other tools such as pip.

Comment: You could just bundle the entire application into an executable with cx_freeze, PyInstaller or py2exe.

Comment: Or you could distribute package tarballs and install them with pip: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#install-packages

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I need this to work with "python setup.py install". I can use pip as a last resort, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to bundle multiple packages together with Python setuptools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708150/is-there-a-way-to-bundle-multiple-packages-together-with-python-setuptools)